# Unclickable buttons in Magento 2 Admin Menu

Tags: php, magento, magento2, magento-1.9

I installed Magento 2.3 (with demo content) successfully using Installatron in cPanel. But the buttons in Admin menu don't work (not clickable). Beside this, there is a problem on the front end: product images don't load on the product pages only (I can see images on the Home page). All other things on the frontend work good. My server settings meets Magento 2 requirements (php 7.1).

Prior to 2.3 version, I installed Magento 1.9.4 at the same server and everything worked good including admin dashboard.

I have tried few solutions that I found on this forum and some other but it didn't help.
I removed var/cache folder and executed the command below through CLI but nothing changed:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

How to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Check if Javascript is loading on the page. In chrome go to Inspect and check the network tab for any 404 or 500 page load errors. I've seen this before and it was Javascript not loading on the page.

Comment: @Chris I asked 2 questions - regarding inactive admin menu buttons and missing product images on the product pages.

1. No Javascript error when admin page loads.

2. There are two .js missing when product page loads (requirejs-config.js, priceBox.js). 
What was your solution?